# Cannot add cognito authentification to aws load balancer (ELB)

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-elb

I am trying to add a cognito auhtentification to my load balancer following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html?icmpid=docs_elbv2_console.

When I setup the authentification process, I have only the "oidc" type, but I expect a "cognito" type :
[image]

When I try the rest api, I have the same problem

> Action type 'authenticate-cognito' must be one of 'redirect,fixed-response,forward,authenticate-oidc'

cognito is not available.

Am i missing some permissions ? I am an  AmazonCognitoPowerUser

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same issue on region eu-west-3 and it's probably a bug at Amazon that costed me a day of my life.
Good thing is you can actually configure *Authenticate OIDC* to behave exactly like *Authenticate Cognito*:

- **Issuer**: `https://cognito-idp.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/[pool-id]` (make sure to use pool-id and not pool-name)
- **Authorization endpoint**: `https://[pool-name].auth.eu-west-3.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize`
- **Token endpoint**: `https://[pool-name].auth.eu-west-3.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token`
- **User info endpoint**: `https://[pool-name].auth.eu-west-3.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo`

The other info to fill should be straightforward.
Make sure to select your scope(s) in the advanced settings and to allow HTTPS outbound traffic on your load balancer security group.

The **Callback URL** of your App client in Cognito should be:

- `https://[CNAME]/oauth2/idpresponse` if using a custom domain to access your final app
- `https://[DNS]/oauth2/idpresponse` if using the load balancer DNS name to access your final app

Comment: [pool-name] or more often [custom-domain-name] if you have one

Comment: eu-north-1 is also missing this feature so I went with the same workaround. Is there any benefit to the "Cognito" authentication as opposed to OIDC other than the slightly simplified config?

Comment: with this  workaround i can only authenticate one appclient i guess?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I was on *eu-west-3*,

By switching in *eu-west-1* or *us-east* it works perfectly,

I guess the option isn't fully deployed yet

Comment: Nine and a half months later, it still isn't fully deployed. Weird.